# How can I simplify code for a choose you own adventure game?

Tags: c++, oop, bandersnatch

I was inspired by the "Black Mirror Bandersnatch" choose your own adventure episode and decided to give it a go myself. I have so far created a somewhat functional skeleton as a template for the rest of the project. I want to see if any good coders have advice for simplifying switch statements that get exponentially bigger as you get further into the game. Here is what I have so far...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Player.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Player player;
    cout << "Health: " << player.GetHealth() << endl;

    int choice = 0;

    cout << "You wake up on Jupiter. There is a tunnel with a mysterious blue light emitting from it in the distance. You look to the right and see a futuristic  factory with strange crafts flying from it. You wonder how you got to Jupiter...\n" << endl;

    cout << "Go to the tunnel(1) \t Go to the factory(2)\n>>> ";
    cin >> choice;


    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "You go towards the tunnel and get attacked by a flying saucer...\n";
            player.DecreaseHealth();
            cout << "Health: " << player.GetHealth() << "\n";
            cout << "You see a secret nazi facility. Go and check it out(1). In the distance you see a TR3-B craft. Do you want to fly it? (2)\n";
            //choice = 0;
            cout << "Go to the secret nazi facility(1) \t Get inside TR3-B(2)\n>>> ";
            cin >> choice;
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    cout << "You go to secret nazi facility...\n";
                    player.DecreaseHealth();
                    cout << "Health: " << player.GetHealth() << "\n";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "You get inside TR3B... \n";
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "You go towards the factory...\n";
            cout << "Health: " << player.GetHealth() << "\n";
            cout << "Do you want to steal element 117(1) or grab TR3-B top secret documents(2)\n";
            cin >> choice;
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    cout << "You steal element 117...\n";
                    player.DecreaseHealth();
                    cout << "Health: " << player.GetHealth() << "\n";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "You grab documents... \n";
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I only have 2 absolute paths with 2 of their own paths. Each case will have 2 more cases added to it. When I get to the third level of the tree there is a whopping total of 16 cases to add. After the third level its 32-64-128 and so forth. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Doing this linearly will get unwieldy very quickly.  Put all the story strings into an array.  Put the choices in an array.  At the beginning of the game you get served string[1] and choice[1].  Depending on which choice you take you get string[2] and choice[2] or string[3] and choice[3].  Perhaps the choices themselves could be objects that contain the string giving you the choice and the identities of the next string for each possibility.  Either way doing this with nested switch case statements will become a mess once it gets much bigger.

Comment: Make a function that takes in parameters such as player object and have enum's like ENTERED_TUNNEL, ATTACKED_MONSTER, GAINED_HEALTH and have all your conditions within that function. That way all your choice statements will call the same function like doSomething(player, SOME_ENUM).

Comment: Make each decision point an object. Call the class a `scene` or a `node` or a `decision` or whatever you want. The `scene` contains its description, its prompt, its possible answers, and a pointer to the next scene associated with each answer. You can create a `GameState` struct to hold any persistent data (maybe you want the game to remember if you grabbed the gun in scene 2 or grabbed the knife instead). Your game is a loop that calls `do_scene(GameState& state)` on each `scene` object, returns a new `scene` in return, and then loops and executes that new scene.

Comment: It also rules out the possibility that two paths get you to the same page of the CYOA book.  I see an object, a class that holds a string for the story, strings for the choices, and ints to correspond to each choice telling what object to go get next.  Think of one class that basically has all the elements of one page of a CYOA book, the story, the choices, and the page numbers to go to.  Then all your code has to do is grab the right page object and print the stuff in it.

Comment: Bottom line -- do not have a program design based on `switch` statements.  That is a recipe for disaster.  Use `switch` statements for simple `if()/else()` conditions, not as a means of designing a program.

Comment: Look into making a finite automata and base your game off that.

Comment: Also consider that a lot of this information can be stored in files, and be read in when the program starts.  What if one of those levels change?  Do you then rewrite the program, or just change the data file that you read in?  Then it doesn't matter how deep the levels go -- at program startup, all that information is stored in a file or set of files, and you just need to build the internal structures from the data in those files.